# Creating an infinite MP4 with FFMPEG (not looping)

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, html5-video, mp4

I know that mp4 streaming is a no-no, this project is just for playing with video :)

I have an infinite h264 stream provided by a Raspberry Pi camera, and I want to wrap it in an infinite mp4 so I can watch it in a browser.

(source) `raspivid -t 0 -w 1640 -h 1232 -fps 20 -b 500000 -vf -hf -o -`

(ffmpeg) `ffmpeg -r 20 -i - -vcodec copy -movflags "frag_keyframe+empty_moov" -f mp4 pipe:1`

What I do is that I pipe (source) into (ffmpeg) and then (ffmpeg) to my program which buffers, uploads to a server, authenticates, etc.

This works fine, and I am able to watch the stream from a browser.

**PROBLEM**: the problem is that (ffmpeg) stops outputting data after 6 minutes.

When the video reaches 6:00, the (ffmpeg) command just stops writing data to its`stdout`.

I tried changing the framerate, bitrate, resolution, etc but nothing makes a difference, it always stops at 6:00.

I checked the (source) command and it is still writing to its own `stdout`.

**QUESTION**: Is there something that I am missing? why does it stop writing to `stdout` after just 6 minutes? is the command missing some flag to allow an infinite mp4?

**EDIT**: added the output of `-report` below.

```
ffmpeg started on 2017-12-26 at 19:59:13
Report written to "ffmpeg-20171226-195913.log"
Command line:
ffmpeg -report -r 20 -i - -vcodec copy -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 pipe:1
ffmpeg version git-2017-12-10-eaff5fc Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1) 20170516
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56.  5.100 / 56.  5.100
  libavcodec     58.  6.103 / 58.  6.103
  libavformat    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100
  libavfilter     7.  7.100 /  7.  7.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '20'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '-'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-movflags' ... matched as AVOption 'movflags' with argument 'frag_keyframe+empty_moov'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'mp4'.
Reading option 'pipe:1' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url -.
Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 20.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: -.
[NULL @ 0x2e7d450] Opening 'pipe:' for reading
[pipe @ 0x2e7db70] Setting default whitelist 'crypto'
[h264 @ 0x2e7d450] Format h264 probed with size=2048 and score=51
[h264 @ 0x2e7d450] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:4096 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[AVBSFContext @ 0x2e8f3e0] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 1
[AVBSFContext @ 0x2e8f3e0] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 1
[AVBSFContext @ 0x2e8f3e0] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] nal_unit_type: 7, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] nal_unit_type: 8, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] nal_unit_type: 5, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] Reinit context to 1648x1232, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x2e7fa60] nal_unit_type: 1, nal_ref_idc: 1
[h264 @ 0x2e7d450] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000 microseconds st:0
[h264 @ 0x2e7d450] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 395264 bytes read:397312 seeks:0 frames:127
Input #0, h264, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 127, 1/1200000: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1640x1232, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url pipe:1.
Applying option vcodec (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument copy.
Applying option f (force format) with argument mp4.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: pipe:1.
[pipe @ 0x2e8ef70] Setting default whitelist 'crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
[mp4 @ 0x2e80680] Empty MOOV enabled; disabling automatic bitstream filtering
Output #0, mp4, to 'pipe:1':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.3.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/10240: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1640x1232, q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 10240 tbn, 20 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[mp4 @ 0x2e80680] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
frame=  140 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=     352kB time=00:00:06.95 bitrate= 415.4kbits/s speed=11.8x    
frame=  152 fps=128 q=-1.0 size=     352kB time=00:00:07.55 bitrate= 382.4kbits/s speed=6.35x    
frame=  164 fps= 94 q=-1.0 size=     352kB time=00:00:08.15 bitrate= 354.3kbits/s speed=4.69x    
frame=  174 fps= 78 q=-1.0 size=     352kB time=00:00:08.65 bitrate= 333.8kbits/s speed=3.86x    
.....
frame= 7342 fps= 20 q=-1.0 size=   22381kB time=00:06:07.05 bitrate= 499.5kbits/s speed=1.02x    
frame= 7354 fps= 20 q=-1.0 size=   22381kB time=00:06:07.65 bitrate= 498.7kbits/s speed=1.02x    
frame= 7366 fps= 20 q=-1.0 size=   22381kB time=00:06:08.25 bitrate= 497.9kbits/s speed=1.02x
```

As you can see, it stoped working at 6:08 on this run. Then it sat idle for a couple minutes and I had to kill the process.

Comment: Run with -report and share log.

Comment: @Mulvya I have added the output with `-report`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you save to disk, changing nothing else but pipe:1 to a file path, does it still stop?

Comment: @Mulvya no, when changing `pipe:1` to `test.mp4` there is no problem. If it matters, I am starting it as a process with `/bin/bash -c "(source) | (ffmpeg)"` with a `ProcessBuilder` from Java, and attaching to the `stdout` stream for reading.

Comment: So, next step is run the command in shell directly and check.

Comment: @Mulvya it works ok when running it directly in the shell like in my previous comment. The reason that made me think `ffmpeg` is causing the issue is that if I skip it and just call from Java: `/bin/bash -c "(source)"` works, but when `ffmpeg` is added then it gets stuck after 6 min: `/bin/bash -c "(source) | (ffmpeg)"`. Seeing this behavior, it is likely that the problem is the way of reading `stdout` of the command. However, It is strange that without `| (ffmpeg)` it works, and that I can clearly see that when added it produces no more output. I'm going to test a bit more. Ideas welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that is was the way I was handling the process.

`ffmpeg` writes something similar to its `-report` to `stderr`:

```
// This line over and over:
frame= 8237 fps= 20 q=-1.0 Lsize=   25192kB time=00:06:51.80 bitrate= 501.2kbits/s speed=1.02x
```

I was not taking this into account, completely ignoring `stderr` until it backed up the stream and the process got stuck :(

Since the logging to `stderr` follows a constant rate (does not depend on bitrate, framerate, etc) the process always got stuck at the same time, in my case around 6:00.

**Solution**: don't forget to read or redirect `stderr`!!